# Are there any tools like landscape.io which work with Mercurial/BitBucket?

Tags: python-3.x, mercurial, continuous-integration, landscape.io

I want to use a tool like landscape.io to keep track of technical debt that people might be accidentally introducing into an open-source project. Unfortunately that tool only seems to work with GitHub.

Is there a similar tool that offers static code analysis as a hosted service that's also compatible with BitBucket and Mercurial?

I'm certain that I could get most of this using a hand-rolled linter running under Jenkins but I'd rather not have to maintain this. It's a nice thing to have not really a core part of the project I want to spend too much time on. In other words I want a ready to roll solution.

My project is in Python 3.x